# adding class to a section when I scroll to it

Tags: javascript, dom

Please, how can I add a class to each section when scrolling to it my problem is that it happens only in the first section.
I am a beginner and the problem is here

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    allSections.forEach(section => {

        let activeLink = document.querySelectorAll("nav a").forEach;

        if(section.getBoundingClientRect().top >= -400 && section.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 150){

            section.classList.add("your-active-class");
            activeLink.classList.add("active-link");

        }

        else{
            section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
            activeLink.classList.remove("active-link");
        }
    
    })
}
```

code is here

```
https://codepen.io/mohamedtharwat000/pen/gOmwqqr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try like this.

```
let navA = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
window.onscroll = function() {
   var scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop

   navA.forEach(a => {     
      var currLink = a;
      var refElement = document.getElementById(currLink.getAttribute("href").substring(1));                                      
      var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect()
  
  var offset   = refElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
 
  if (offset <= scrollPos &&       offset + refElement.offsetHeight + 200 > scrollPos) {
            navA.forEach(item=>{
              item.classList.remove("active-link");
            })
            sections.forEach(sec=>{
              sec.classList.remove("your-active-class");
            });
           currLink.classList.add("active-link");
           refElement.classList.add("your-active-class");
        }
        else{
            currLink.classList.remove("active-link");
            refElement.classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
 });    
}
navA.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
    navA.forEach(item=>{
      item.classList.remove("active-link");
    });
    a.classList.add("active-link");
    let target = document.getElementById(currLink.getAttribute("href").substring(1));
    sections.forEach(sec=>{
      sec.classList.remove("your-active-class");
    });
    target.classList.add("your-active-class");
  });  
});
```

Please confirm this URL https://codepen.io/btsm0714/pen/JjWRqXZ

Comment: thanks, it works well with the navbar but all sections are active is there a way to active only link in the navbar and the section it refers to

Comment: I fixed when click navbar. I posted here and also edited code pen

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly know what were you trying to achieve with `activeLink` variable, but removing it seems to solve you issue.

```
window.onscroll = function() {

allSections.forEach(section => {

    if(section.getBoundingClientRect().top >= -400 && section.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 150)
        section.classList.add("your-active-class");
    else
        section.classList.remove("your-active-class");  
})}
```

Comment: how can I add active class to navbar links also

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this function, which takes the amount of px scrolled from top.

```
function scrollFunction() {
 if(document.documentElement.scrollTop >= **Your Value** && document.documentElement.scrollTop <= **Your Value**){
            section.classList.add("your-active-class");
            activeLink.classList.add("active-link");
        }else{            
            section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
            activeLink.classList.remove("active-link");
        }

}
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};
```

I'm calling it on window.onScroll and it's working fine.
Hope I helped.